# What is a secure set of permissions to give a set of files to be backed up?

Tags: linux, backup, file-permissions

On our server we have a number of users (i.e. clients) who need their code to be backed up. Their file permissions are usually `650` with user and group being `user:user` (where `user` is the actual user name).

In crontab we have a user, `backup`, that backups all the desired file paths via tarsnap. The problem is that because of the file permissions, `backup` can't access these. I can think of four solutions:

1. Set the cronjob to run as root. This is the easiest fix but I don't know if there is a security issue here.
2. Create a group that all users we want to backup and `backup` belong to. Set the default permissions to set the group for all these users to that group...the `backup` group seems like a good choice for a group name. This seems a bit difficult though. **How do I change the default permissions for each user so that each file touched has the user `user` and group `backup`?**
3. Modify the group permissions on all the files we want to backup. This is also easy but it also means every time a file is touched (i.e. modified or created) we'll have to modify the group. Not ideal.
4. Make the files world-readable. Is this a security issue?

**What would be a reasonable configuration so that I can easily backup these files?**

---

*Just thought of one more…*

5. Add the `backup` user to each of the user groups I wish to backup. This resolves the problem of shared access.

In doing some research, it seems like the semantics of `/var/backups` and the `backup` user are unclear. [It doesn't seem dangerous to put backups in `/var/backups`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68698/is-it-bad-dangerous-inappropriate-to-put-arbitrary-backups-in-var-backups) but the recommendation there was not to use it for user backups since [the behavior is undocumented (since 2001)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=122038). Practically speaking, it seems that a lot of processes use `/var/backups` and the `backup` user ("user" is the wrong word to describe this though...since `backup` is not a proper "user" with a home directory, etc.) so [in recommending its usage, we're not advocating something new.](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2005-January/072435.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should really got with just running cronjob under `root`

Reasons:

- You will avoid non-backed up files due to user setting permission to something like 700. For example ssh keys must have this permission or SSH refuses to use them if I remember correctly.
  When doing a backup under `root` you will always know that you copied all the files.
- If you make users part of the same backup group, they will be able to access eachother's files. I think there are too many possible security issues caused by said reconfiguration to use `backup` group than to simply use `cronjob` for user `root`.

Comment: +1 from me.  Backup is a system function; under UNIX, those are supposed to happen as root.

Comment: @edvinas.me What do you think of my last possible solution (above) that I just added?

Comment: After some thinking, this is the right answer.